# Is it possible to override font size limit on labels in R plotly bar chart?

Tags: r, plotly

I have a `plotly` grouped bar chart with labels. I can change the font size on the labels, but `plotly` won't allow the fonts to get exceed a certain limit that appears to be determined by the width/height of the bars. This becomes a problem when there are a larger number of groups and/or values to graph. In some of these cases, the text won't become larger than, for example, 8 point font. Is there a way to exceed this limitation?

Here's some sample code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
data.frame(Desc = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
           Group = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group1", "Group2", "Group1", "Group2"), 
           Value = c(5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 3)) %>% 
  plotly::plot_ly(data = .) %>% 
  plotly::add_trace(x = ~Value, 
                    y = ~Desc, 
                    color = ~Group,
                    type = 'bar', 
                    text = ~Value, 
                    textposition = "outside", 
                    textfont = list(size = 10), # size is defined here
                    )
```

This chart, with font size of 10, outputs:
[image]

If I change the font to 30 point, then:
[image]

Finally, at 50 point (where it is unchanged relative to 30 point):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `layout` and set `uniformtext` to change the text size. I increased the x axis range to make the large numbers fit.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
library(dplyr);
library(plotly)})
data.frame(Desc = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
           Group = c("Group1", "Group2", "Group1", "Group2", "Group1", "Group2"), 
           Value = c(5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 3)) %>% 
    plotly::plot_ly(data = .) %>% 
    plotly::add_trace(x = ~Value, 
                      y = ~Desc, 
                      color = ~Group,
                      type = 'bar', 
                      text = ~Value, 
                      textposition = "outside"
    ) %>% layout(xaxis=list(range=c(0, 7)),
                 uniformtext=list(minsize=80, mode='show'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I get the following error: "'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'uniformtext'". Is it a version error?

Comment: That is possible. I am on R-devel, plotly_4.9.2.1.

Comment: I updated to the latest version on CRAN and it's working. Looks like I asked this question just at the right time. Thanks for your help!